# Add function to excel not by add-ins

Tags: excel, vba

How I can add a `VBA code` to be as **main function** in excel?

I need an effective way to add this function to the excel program which allows it to run on multiple locations.

I tried to add it as add-ins, but I faced a problem when I shared it on google drive in an attempt to allow it to be used on other devices.

The function name converted to a path **"c:/../.."** and the cell converted from the correct value to **#NAME! Error**.

Comment: This is very unclear. Excel doesn't have a concept of "main function". Please clarify.

Comment: simply I want to add an function to excel function so when I type =fun.... it complete the name of my function and I can use it I want to do it on 3 devices because there's a shared file between those 3 devices and I need that custom function to be in place to avoid the problem of not finding the function I hope you got the idea

Comment: Why not just distribute it as a user defined function in a macro-enabled workbook?

Comment: then tell me how please I don't know the steps

Comment: give me the steps in separate comment so I can choose it as correct answer, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Start your code with Function rather than Sub. Define inputs/outputs. Put the code in any .xlsm or .xlsb files you want to access the function from.